# Use API with api key using javascript

Tags: javascript, api

so I want to access an api from  mashape.com but the link always give me

```
{"message":"Missing Mashape application key. Go to http:\/\/docs.mashape.com\/api-keys to learn how to get your API application key."}
```

the following example the website provides to show how to request the api using .Net :

```
Task<HttpResponse<MyClass>> response = Unirest.post("https://andruxnet-random-famous-quotes.p.mashape.com/?cat=movies")
.header("X-Mashape-Key", "huni7LtgROmshd8R87ecu5BQdcY1p1Cf0Uijsn5mgXEaDEtsbP")
.header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
.header("Accept", "application/json")
.asJson();
```

I want to know how to do that same task using javascript and what is the URL to the api in that example .

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with Ajax: here it is if you're using jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://andruxnet-random-famous-quotes.p.mashape.com/?cat=movies",
    method: 'post', 
    header: {
       'X-Mashape-Key': 'your api key',
       'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-rule coded',
       'Accept': 'application/json'
    },
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function(data) { doSomething with your data here }
});
```

Comment: thanks but .. in line 5 in your code ..it's Mashape not Mashable in case someone was to copy it ..... you made me waste unnecessary amount of time trying to find what's wrong btw :D .. still thanks a lot ... UPDATE : still is there some way I can access that api using URL in the browser ?

Comment: Since the api seems to be looking for a post, you'll have to use something like `Postman`. This way you can send the correct headers. Thanks for the spelling mistake. I was doing this on my tablet so it looks like it autocorrected.